# C#, Sharepoint - GetDescription() & SetDescription() of the Taxonomy Term

Tags: c#, sharepoint, taxonomy-terms

I want to be able to manage the GetDescription() and SetDescription() of the Taxonomy Term(as a managed metadata).
In order to get the value of the Description, not of the Label of the Taxonomy Term. 
How should I manage these functions?

Any suggestion would be very much appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. What did you try so far?

Comment: @TheTanic I've never worked  with Taxonomy before as I'm a novice in Sharepoint as well. I've managed only the Label or (Title)of the Term, but I need to know the proper use of the GetDescription() and SetDescription(). There's nothing related to this topic on  the site.

Comment: You mean what the parameter `LCID` is, or what exactly is the question? Description is just a text property you can use for describing the term.

Comment: @Raziel I want to be able to get the description of each Term of the TermSet....refering to this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee563467(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("Site URL"))
            {
                TaxonomySession taxonomySession = new TaxonomySession(site);
                TermStore termStore = taxonomySession.TermStores["MMD Service"];
                Group group = termStore.Groups["Term Group"];               
                TermSet termSet = group.TermSets["Term Set"];
                Term term = termSet.Terms["term"];
                term.SetDescription("Test", 1033);           
                termStore.CommitAll();            
            }
```